# How do I bypass the ac rectifier in a guitar amp so I can power it directly with DC power source instead of mains?

Tags: bridge-rectifier

I have a guitar amp that died recently, the primary coil of the transformer lacks continuity when tested with a multi-meter. I am trying to power it with a 9V power source instead of AC power outlet. I am intending to bypass the rectifier but I'm not sure where to hook up the 9V source on the circuit board.

The transformer outputs 10.5 volts and I figured 9V should do the trick if I don't pass it through the diodes. The fuse is rated at 1 Amp and the 9V source is also 1 Amp.

I diagrammed out the power source circuit. Hopefully that is enough information. Pretty new to all this stuff. Thanks in advance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpdkCS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

--Update--

Looks like I'm going to need something like this to create a power supply that is split into +9V and -9V with a ground at 0V:

[image: Discrete Rail Splitter]

Found this and more [here](http://tangentsoft.net/elec/vgrounds.html)

Comment: Not sure you can do that, looks like you have a split rail there.

Comment: the fuse is at the high voltage side, the low voltage size would need to draw 10 Amps before it blows. Check the power rating of the amp and make sure your supply can supply it.

Comment: The output on the transformer says: 10.5V -0 -10.5V 0.6A

Comment: I guess their goal was to sell more transformers than fuses then? lol

Comment: 10.5V should be AC voltage. That means DC source has to be about ±13V DC, *maybe* 12V would work too, but could give some undesired distortion. You will need two adapters (13 or 12V DC) to make the positive and the negative supply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diode bridge is used together with a center tapped secondary to create plus and minus supplies.  You can't just replace that with a single-output supply.  What you show won't work.

You can get your own ±9 V supply, then connect its three leads to the three nets you show going into the dashed block at right.  Since the diodes would be reverse-biased if you connect the external supply correctly, there is no need to remove them.  In fact, they give you some protection against connecting the external supply in reverse.

Comment: So you are saying that the entire circuit would have to be redesigned to work with a normal 9v supply? So a battery could never power it?

Comment: @jSnake04 You would need two batteries.  One to generate the positive voltage, one for the negative.  Possibly two 4.5V batteries.

Comment: 10.5V should be AC voltage. DC source has to be about ±13V DC.

Comment: I came across [this](http://tangentsoft.net/elec/vgrounds.html). Looks like one of these might be what I need to 'split the rail.' It would be great to be able to use batteries or a wall brick power supply.

Comment: @jSn: I wouldn't use one of those splitter kludges, especially for a audio circuit.  If you can't find a bipolar supply, use two supplies or two batteries.  Two 12 V wall warts would work, assuming that's the correct voltage.  Such wall warts are cheap and available.

Comment: What amp rating would those two 12v wall warts need? would two 0.5 amp be sufficient or would they both need to be 1amp? The whole thing says 25 watts on the back.

Comment: @jSn: It depends on how much current this device needs worst case.  It seems it will never require more than 25 W, but could be significantly less.  To be sure, get two 12 V 1A wall power supplies.

Answer (score 0):

If the transformer died then I would remove it, the rectifier diodes, and the power cord.  Mains power is dangerous, so make sure there isn't any chance of getting across it or charged components.

It appears that you are generating both positive and negative rails (positive on C1 and negative on C2).  I would apply the appropriate voltage across each cap.

Comment: I don't think that removing the bridge is a good idea, a much better bet is to replace the transformer. They're not difficult parts to source after all! :)

Comment: That is proper way for sure.  They are, however, more expensive than a lot of consumer electronics.  My thought is that he probably doesn't care about a kludge as long as he saves a few $.

Comment: Saving a buck and learning a bit is my goal. ;) So if I understand correctly. 9V positive side is good, but the negative side would go to C2's negative? Then remove diodes and all?